# Pass text file as argument/variable [bash]

Tags: bash, arguments, getopts

I am trying to pass a text file as a specific argument and print its name and content...

```
#!/bin/bash

## set input args
while getopts "f" option; do
    case "${option}" in
        f)
          arg3=${OPTARG};;  
      esac
done

## script
echo $arg3
echo $(cat $arg3)
```

(for running it: `sh myscript.sh -f filelist`)

Something is really wrong because even the file name is not appearing! (and curiously, in bash everything goes well, why?).

Comment: Where did you set `name`? `cat $name` should be `cat $arg3`

Comment: Also remember to quote your variables: `cat "$arg3"`

Comment: It needs to be `getopts "f:"` option`. The `:` indicates that the option has an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According @Barmar's answer (thanks!) I forgot the colon with `f`... but, as I was trying to make this argument *optional*, this should be after. Based on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697692/7580614) and @Barmar's point, the "final" code could be like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

## set input args
while getopts ":f" option; do
    case "${option}" in
        f)
          # Check next positional parameter
          eval nextopt=\${$OPTIND}
          # existing or starting with dash?
          if [[ -n $nextopt && $nextopt != -* ]] ; then
            OPTIND=$((OPTIND + 1))
            arg3=$nextopt
          else
            echo "Not filelist specified, closing..." && exit
          fi
        ;;
      esac
done

## script
echo $arg3
echo $(cat $arg3)
```